# White screen on running php project

Tags: php, mysql, server, xampp, port

so i am getting the white screen error on running my php project.

I have tried changing the port from 'listen 80' to 'listen 8081', disabling my firewall, running new php file on the same project folder(which works btw), changing browser, run by administrator but, still have not resolved this. Can anybody help? Apache error.log shows upto the following code

```
[Mon Jul 22 21:58:48.438621 2019] [core:warn] [pid 6868:tid 608] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Mon Jul 22 21:58:48.469867 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6868:tid 608] AH00455: Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 22 21:58:48.469867 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6868:tid 608] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: May 29 2019 11:22:50
[Mon Jul 22 21:58:48.469867 2019] [core:notice] [pid 6868:tid 608] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Jul 22 21:58:48.469867 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6868:tid 608] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 9060
[Mon Jul 22 21:58:49.094847 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9060:tid 600] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: Do you have any other error logs in your log folder? There are often an error log per site set up, depending on how it's configured.

Comment: i have access.log, install.log, ssl_request.log and an httpd.pid file in the log folder

Answer (score 0):

if the project is already working, it'd be good to check the sintax in your php scripts. Turn on the 'notices' and 'errors' to check it and it'll show you any errors. Maybe this could help you.